# c++ macro which accepts colon and value with

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
CREATE message = (PHRASE: "thankyou") //define message variable with value "thankyou"
```

how can I achieve (PHRASE: "thankyou") to make it C++11 valid code?

Comment: Nick, I think your question is highly unclear, thus the downvotes... Please edit your question!

Comment: What do you want `(PHRASE: "thankyou")` to expand to? And why do you want this exact `(X : Y)` syntax?

Comment: I'm trying to create a pseucode. I want to make (PHRASE: "thankyou") a valid C++  syntax. I've tried with macro function #define PHRASE: but didn't work

Comment: Here is what you can do with the preprocessor : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_preprocessor.htm

Comment: Thank you, but I already have tried this and it's not helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
#define PHRASE false? ""
```

Then using it like this:

```
std::cout << (PHRASE: "thankyou");
```

will output `thankyou`.

Comment: This answer is almost mean in giving momentum over this first hurdle, as OP will just crash head-first into the next one. Still a funny macro though ;)

Comment: "In C++ it's harder to shoot yourself in the foot, but when you do, you blow off your whole leg."    — Bjarne Stroustrup.